# How to determine what a process is doing when it's using 95% cpu

Tags: troubleshooting, process

For some reason, IIS process (W2WP.EXE) is consuming 95-99% CPU at at all times. I'm trying to determine what is going on but I can't see anything obvious. Last time we saw this issue it was because the website was trying to log data to a log file in an infinate loop but I dont see anythig like that now. I have run procmon for 5 minutes but I don't really see anything indicating what the issue might be or what it is doing. Of course, I'm no expert.

How can I determine what a process is doing that is causing it use consume so much CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you isolate which web application is causing the problem by turning each off in turn.

If the application is asp.net, you could attach it to a debugger. Or use [Jetbrains Profiler.](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

Comment: There is only one site running, but we cant attach a debugger because it's deployed in release mode. I'll try the profiler and see what i get

Comment: have you tried recycling the app pool? does the event viewer give any indication? are you using any logging?

Comment: yes but it continues to occur.

Comment: this page might help http://blogs.technet.com/b/marcelofartura/archive/2006/09/15/456363.aspx

Comment: JetBrains was a big failure, at best it crashed the process. I used ProcExplorer to determine what the issue was and it pointed to something happeneing with .NET so I went ahead and used RedGate Profiler to see wtf was going on and now I'm trying to figure out how to fix it. thanks.